# visualvm - what included in to "Used heap"?

Tags: java, heap-memory, visualvm

I'm trying to understand output of **visualvm** (needs to create console util with same info) - but can't understood - which **Java** memory parts included in to "*Used heap*"?

For example - let's take:

```
$ jmap -heap 27200
Attaching to process ID 27200, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 20.45-b01

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 4 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 352452608 (336.125MB)
   used     = 319379152 (304.5836944580078MB)
   free     = 33073456 (31.541305541992188MB)
   90.61619768181713% used
From Space:
   capacity = 2686976 (2.5625MB)
   used     = 2326528 (2.21875MB)
   free     = 360448 (0.34375MB)
   86.58536585365853% used
To Space:
   capacity = 2752512 (2.625MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 2752512 (2.625MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 715849728 (682.6875MB)
   used     = 253887896 (242.1263656616211MB)
   free     = 461961832 (440.5611343383789MB)
   35.46664698879371% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 185139200 (176.5625MB)
   used     = 126335488 (120.48291015625MB)
   free     = 58803712 (56.07958984375MB)
   68.23810840707965% used
```

My suggestion - "*Used heap*" for **visualvm** is:

`Eden Space` + `From Space` + `To Space` + `Old Generation` (without `Perm Generation` - as it is displayed on other tab)

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your assumption is correct, the graph shows an orange area which represent the total  heap space pre-allocated for that JVM instance (i.e., defined by -Xmx, -Xms) and the blue area that is usually oscillating is the real-time monitoring of the heap space, which is comprised of the Young (Eden, Survivor = From & To) and the Old generation spaces.

So, if you need to parse the info from jmap and present this data in a Command Line Interface utility, you would need to parse all the lines containing this info (excluding the "Perm Generation" as you pointed out):
used     = 319379152 (304.5836944580078MB)

A suggestion to improve your tool would be to present a special report focusing on major changes on the Old Generation space, because that would reflect Full GC cycles (which are more critical than the cycles in the Young area since the 'stop-the-world' algorithm would  impact your application's performance), you could check the frequency of such cycles and, if you want a more sophististicated approach, parsing the GC logs for the duration of the Full GC Cycles.

I have a post in my blog about it in case your are interested:
https://marcelorjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/logs-do-garbage-collector/